# Deleted files by mistake , apps doesn't open from terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04

I deleted alot of files by mistake , after deletion , the background is changed , some user specified settings were set to it's default , i cannot open any application from terminal , but the application folder are still available .
like anaconda ,
i type anaconda-navigator in terminal and the app isn't found , given that it's folder isn't deleted

SOLVED:


PROBLEM : accidentally deleted bashrc file


SOLUTION : restored the default one and added all missing programs to PATH

Comment: Mohye: I suggest you reinstall the apps that are not running.

Comment: all of the files are still there , i've life 250+ gb of app data , they're still there , but the apps aren't running

Comment: How did you delete files?  Did you just move them to trash, hopefully not emptying trash also?

Comment: unfortunately i did empty the trash

Comment: Without some details as to what files you deleted, I can't see that we can help. If you use commands, your command `history` should refresh your memory, if you used package tools, package logs will help (`/etc/apt/apt/history.log`), but a user tool can't remove that many critical files as that requires elevated privileges (`sudo` etc)

Comment: The files were deleted from the home directory , i deleted multiple files on purpose but unfortunately it seems like i selected some system files by mistake while deleting those files , as i said , the anaconda folder is still there sizes around 12gb but i cannot access it from the terminal

Comment: Would say to backup any files you can and delete the apps that don't work and start over.  There are ways of trying to recover files, but takes a long time and not all files would be recovered unless you are very lucky.

Comment: I found the problem, i accidently deleted the bashrc file